# Is there a way to modify attribute options with a percent value?

Tags: ubercart

I'm using Drupal Ubercart and I have created an attribute that should affect the price of the product using the attribute. The problem I have is that out of box, it can only affect the price by adding or subtracting a value. I wish to affect the price using a percent-value. Is there a "clean" way of achieving this?